# Can't make multiple select in registration form

Tags: laravel, select, many-to-many, user-input

I use the basic registration form but I want to add a multiple select, a User can have multiple Skills and select them when he register.
My problem is that when I select multiples values Laravel only take the last one, so I search on the web for a solution and they say to add [] after my class name, so this is what I do :

```
 <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <?php $competences = \App\Competence::all(); ?>
                            <select name="competences[]" multiple="" class="form-control">
                                <option value="" selected disabled style="display:none">choose your school</option>
                                @foreach ($competences as $competence)
                                    <option value="{{ $competence->id }}">{{ $competence->name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

But now, when I submit the form the page reload and stay in the register form, and the user is not register... I don't know what to do, anyone of you have a solution ?

Here is how I check the competences in my registerController

```
 $competences =  $data['competences'];
    foreach ($competences as $comp){
        $user->competences()->save(Competence::find($comp));
    }
```

Comment: do you have competences relation method in your user model?

Comment: you should use `multiple="multiple"` or just `multiple` like:
`<select name="competences[]" multiple="multiple" ... > `

Comment: Yes Erkan my relations works, when I add thru phpmyadmin in my pivot table i can see them in my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `multiple="multiple"` OR just `multiple` in blade.php:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <?php $competences = \App\Competence::all(); ?>
        <select name="competences[]" class="form-control" multiple>
            <option value="" selected disabled style="display:none">choose your school</option>
            @foreach ($competences as $competence)
            <option value="{{ $competence->id }}">{{ $competence->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

then in your controller, verify that you're actually getting the data in the form of an array by just printing `$data`

```
return $data;
```

Comment: Still the same error, when i press the button the page reload and stay on the form, and nothing added to my database, and I can't show the $data, the page refresh instantly

Comment: I found the solution, I'm stupid I put my competence as a string in the validator, thanks ^^

Comment: Also, do you know why when I import bootstrap and jQuery the dropdown menu of the current logged user stop working ?

Comment: It just might be the issue of placement of libraries **I think**

Comment: I try to place all my includes before or after the app.js and still the same problem, that's strange

Comment: Bootstrap I think, I just include bootstrap and jQuery, before include these files the dropdown works